# Yosemite - Require password after sleep is disabled

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

I am trying to prevent the system to always ask for the password when it wakes up from sleep.

- I have a MacbookPro with Yosemite 10.10.5.
- User has admin rights and password different than the iCloud one.
- FileVault is off.

The System Preferences > Security and Privacy > "Require password [5 seconds] after sleep or screen saver begins" is disabled and there's no way to enable it.

If I execute `defaults read com.apple.screensaver` i get:

```
{
    askForPassword = 0;
}
```

If I execute `defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 3600` the defaults don't change...

Comment: Are you using your own Mac or a company supplied Mac? That the option is disabled suggests a managed default is in place.

Comment: It's my own Mac :(

Comment: In the same time, if I create a new user, for that one I can access the option. So there's something about this user that is messed up...

Answer (score 3):

Run in Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool false
```

Comment: defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool false removed the grey out option and allowed me to change the settings. thank you

Comment: Does this require a reboot? Hasn't seemed to change anything for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaults write` no longer works as of 10.13.

https://blog.kolide.com/screensaver-security-on-macos-10-13-is-broken-a385726e2ae2
http://www.openradar.me/35462422

For those who have been searching for a way to do this via profiles, you can use this gist: 
https://gist.github.com/mcw0933/21b8a9e292e83c69931f5de0d2ae1883

Or follow these steps:

1. Create a file called `askforpassworddelay.mobileconfig` with the xml file contents below.
2. Change `__YOUR_NAME__` to something more meaningful if you like.
3. Change the `askForPasswordDelay` value to your desired setting, in seconds.  In the file below, it's 5 seconds.
4. Save the file.
5. Open a terminal window, change directory to the file location, and run `/usr/bin/profiles -I -F askforpassworddelay.mobileconfig`.  Or, launch the Profiles prefpane in System Preferences and then use the UI to install this file manually.

File contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>PayloadContent</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
      <string>Security &amp; Privacy</string>
      <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
      <true/>
      <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.__YOUR_NAME__.config.screensaver</string>
      <key>PayloadType</key>
      <string>com.apple.screensaver</string>
      <key>PayloadUUID</key>
      <string>966eb7be-81bd-f8cc-f3e3-078d93f1b4a4</string>
      <key>PayloadVersion</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>askForPassword</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
      <string>Security &amp; Privacy</string>
      <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
      <true/>
      <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.__YOUR_NAME__.config.screensaver</string>
      <key>PayloadType</key>
      <string>com.apple.screensaver</string>
      <key>PayloadUUID</key>
      <string>966eb7be-81bd-f8cc-f3e3-078d93f1b4a5</string>
      <key>PayloadVersion</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>askForPasswordDelay</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>PayloadDescription</key>
  <string>screen saver password delay settings</string>
  <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
  <string>screen saver password delay</string>
  <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.__YOUR_NAME__.config.screensaver</string>
  <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
  <string>__YOUR_NAME__</string>
  <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
  <false/>
  <key>PayloadScope</key>
  <string>System</string>
  <key>PayloadType</key>
  <string>Configuration</string>
  <key>PayloadUUID</key>
  <string>0dc319a0-c331-0131-eeb5-000c294ab81b</string>
  <key>PayloadVersion</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Link only answer may not be very helpful as the link are liable to get expired. Consider quoting the linked content as part of the answer

Comment: Hi Nimesh.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Adding large inline files is not as easy to do on Ask Different as it is on Stack Overflow, so I thought a gist might be better.  Hope the edits help.

Comment: Tried this on a Monterey (Mac OS 12) machine and got this: 
`profiles tool no longer supports installs. Use System Preferences Profiles to add configuration profiles.`

Comment: Duly noted, @TonyAdams , thanks!  Does the 2nd part of step 4 still work for you?  Happy to edit the answer if need be.  Lmk!

Comment: @mcw The step 4 I'm seeing just says "save the file". I do not see a second part?

Comment: Ooops!  Step 5.  "Or, launch the Profiles prefpane in System Preferences and then use the UI to install this file manually."  Sounds like that's what the command line response is instructing you to do.  Does that part work?