# osx require password after sleep greyed out

Tags: security, system-settings, profile-manager

I don't have the option to change the delay on "require password xx after sleep or screen saver begins.

For security, I would like to change it to "immediately" instead of 5 seconds.

I obviously have admin privilege (I'm also the only user on the Mac)
I thought that was due from a restriction in mobile profile, so I removed some of the profiles that could have prevented me to change this setting, but no luck
how can I change this?

PS Advanced user : use ID 501 group staff
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you try [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234840/88313) and see if it helps?

Comment: defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool false removed the grey out option and allowed me to change the settings. thank you

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you!  I'll flag this as a duplicate of that question.